# How to move text in the input field?

Tags: html, css, input

So this is my first crack at a form and I'm undoubtedly running into a few bumps here and there. But all around it has been a fun process and has boosted my web development ego tremendously :P.

Well I'm having problems moving the text(where the user would actually start typing (not the placeholder text it's where I would like it)) over in my input fields I've tried using `input.text{padding-left:25px;}`, `input[type="text"]{padding-left:25px;}`, and some more things in my general search of the issue on Stack Overflow, to no avail.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html{  
  background:url("blurredNight.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
}

body{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.fixedWidth{
 width: 1136px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#topBar{
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 59.5px;
 background-color: rgba(107,63,160,0.5);
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#formDiv{
 background-color:rgba(107,63,160,0.4);
 padding-left:35px;
 padding-right:35px;
 padding-top:35px;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 width: 450px;
 float: left;
 left: 50%;
 position: relative;
   margin-top:30px;
 margin-left: -260px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   top: 113px;
}

#headerDiv{
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 30px;
 position: relative;

}

#header{
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 200%;
 font-weight: bold;
 bottom: 20px;
}

.inputTagz{
 padding-left: 25px;
 cursor: text;
 font-size: 17.5px;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: px;
 padding-top: 11px;
 padding-bottom: 11px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top:20px;
   font-weight:700;
}
input.name{
 padding-left: 25px;
}

.inputTagz::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz::-moz-placeholder {
 padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
 padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz:-ms-input-placeholder { 
 padding-left:25px; 
}

#name{
 background-image: url("man.svg");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
 background-position: 11px 8px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#emailPhone{
 background-image: url("mail.svg");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
 background-position: 11px 8px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#password{
 background-image: url("lock.svg");
 background-size: 30px 30px;
 background-position: 11px 8px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#buttonBlack{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float:left;
 width: 100%;
 border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color: rgb(107,63,160);
 color:white;
 font-size:24px;
 padding-top:22px;
 padding-bottom:22px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 position: relative;
 left: 3px;
   margin-top:15px;
   font-weight:700;
 }

#buttonBlack:hover{
 background-color: rgba(107,63,160,0.2);
 color: #0493bd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="fixedWidth">
        <div id="topBar">
            <div class="fixedWidth"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="formDiv">
            <form class="mainForm" id="formId">
                <div id="headerDiv">
                     <h2 id="header">
        Open your world.
       </h2>

                </div>
                <p>
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" class="inputTagz" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input name="emailPhone" type="text" placeholder="Phone or Email" id="emailPhone" class="inputTagz" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="inputTagz" />
                </p>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="buttonBlack" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[A link to RT code so you can see it in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gajgrY)

[image: How it looks on my screen....For now anyways.]

Comment: `<input type="text" style="padding-left: 25px;"/>`

Comment: well just a suggestion use `<input type="text" style="text-align:center"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding-left` on your text box and remove the padding from the `:placeholder` style

Remove these:

```
.inputTagz::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz::-moz-placeholder {
    padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    padding-left:25px; 
}
.inputTagz:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    padding-left:25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in your CodePEN, I've deleted all the other selectors that you've created (that add the `padding-left`), and I've only added this one:

```
input[type="text"]{
    padding-left: 25px !important;
}
```

And it worked like a charm. The text was pushed 25px from the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
 input[type=text],input[type=password]  {
     padding-left: 70px;
 }
```

Use the right selectors, in your case is type text/password, or create your own class.

Answer (score -1):

You can also simply add this. Though it will center your text.

```
input{
    text-align: center
}
```